# Can't get PHP to pull line entry from mySQL as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Ok fellas, I've been working with a SQL database via PHP for a couple days here now at work and I cannot for the life of me get it to work I have someone else who worked on this project and they have all sorts of functions that work at pulling one element out of the line, but I'm trying to pull an entire line IE one persons data in the SQL database.

Here is the code they have that pulls one entry from the database

```
public function interact($query,$resultVal) {

        // Create a new mysqli to get the database
        $db = new mysqli("$My_IP","$username","$password","calendar");

        // If there is an error connecting to mysql, show an error to the user
        if ($db->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
        }
        // If there is no database to get the information from, send an error
        if(!$db) {
            echo "Error: Could not acces database in mySQL";
            exit;
        }

        // Select the calendar database to use
        mysql_select_db("calendar");

        if($resultVal) { 
            //Get result using the $query
            $result =  mysql_query($query);

            return $result;
        } 
        else {
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
```

Which is called using this:

```
$variable = $dbact ->interact($query, true);
```

So now I'm trying to get it to work by calling an entire row, heres the function I wrote:

```
public funciton get_person_data($username)
    {
        $dbact = new DbInteraction();
        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, phone, email, contact FROM person WHERE username = ".$username;

        $result = $dbact->interact($query, true);
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        return $data;
    }
```

Which I then call via

```
$info = $dbact->get_person_data($username);
```

Then I use a mySQL fetch array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            $name = $row['first_name'];
            echo $name;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been stuck on this forever.
Thank you for looking!

Comment: `funciton` doesn't look particularly promising...

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a couple of things. First, you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` in there. So it connects in `mysqli` (in OOP mode no less) and then it uses `mysql_query()` (which is procedural). That's just weird. The way to to a query in OOP is

```
$db->query($query);
```

Second, why are you creating a DB connection inside your function? I'd create it outside and pass your `$db` as a parameter.

```
$db = new mysqli("$My_IP","$username","$password","calendar");
// If there is an error connecting to mysql, show an error to the user
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
    }
    // If there is no database to get the information from, send an error
    if(!$db) {
        echo "Error: Could not acces database in mySQL";
        exit;
    }

public function interact($query, $resultVal, \mysqli $db) {
    $result =  $db->query($query);
    if($resultVal) return $result;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I missed that he was mixing those two libraries

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a project that got handed down to me from a guy this summer, I've just been (trying) to clean it up and add some functionality. He's mixed mysql and mysqli all through it. I appreciate the demonstration, it really means alot!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `mysql_fetch_array()` twice. Once in `get_person_data` and once in your while loop. If you're just trying to get one row, then why do you have a while loop in the first place? It should be:

```
$info = $dbact->get_person_data($username);
$name = $info['first_name'];
```

Note, you were also doing `mysql_fetch_array` on `$data`, which wasn't defined as far as I can tell (should have been `$info`, if `mysql_fetch_array` was the right code to use there)